# ¿Cómo puedo deshabilitar un botón desde una actividad a la que no pertenece?

Tags: android

Os explico en qué consiste mi problema. Estoy en una determinada actividad en la que aparece un botón, que al pulsarlo hace que se cierre esa actividad y que deshabilite uno de los botones de la actividad que se muestra al cerrar la actividad en la que me encuentro actualmente. El problema es que me da un error de null. Este es mi código:
Actividad 1, en la que se encuentra el botón a deshabilitar:

```
private Button miBoton;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_anterior);

        miBoton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);
}
public Button getMiBoton() {
        return miBotonFinalizar;
}
```

Este es el código de la segunda actividad, en la que se debe deshabilitar el botón de la primera actividad al pulsar el botón de esta actividad.

```
ActividadAnterior a = new ActividadAnterior();

Button finalizar = new Button();
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_this);

        a = new AdminActivity();
        finalizar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.boton);

        finalizar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnCLickListener) {
            a.getMiBoton().setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inicia la actividad pasandole un  "identificador" para luego poder usarlo

```
startActivityForResult(intent, CHILD_REQUEST);
```

Y recoge el valor en el siguiente metodo

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == CHILD_REQUEST) {

            switch (resultCode) {
                case RESULT_OK:

                    break;

                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    // Cancelación o cualquier situación de error
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Y ahora en el ativity que iniciamos,para mandar al activity que has lanzado, solo tienes que poner un result

```
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta de @manuelrobles es correcta, escribo esto para ampliar un poco el panorama. Lo que intentas hacer en tu código es algo que no debería hacerse nunca en Android.

`a = new AdminActivity();`: Las actividades de android no deben ser instanciadas 'manualmente', el framework de Android es quien se encarga de instanciar y levantar las activities. El programador siempre debe invocar una activity usando `startActivity(...)` o un método similar.

`a.getMiBoton()`: Nunca debes referenciar un método o atributo de una activity de esta forma. Ya que es el framework de Android es el encargado de instanciar y manipular el ciclo de vida de una actividad, no es recomendable intentar acceder a sus métodos/atributos de forma directa, ya que no podemos estar seguros de que la activity en cuestión se encuentra activa (y no destruída por ejemplo). La forma correcta de pasar información entre activities es a través del [intent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) o en su defecto utilizando [startActivityForResult](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result?hl=es-419)